# Find, isolate, reconstruct en replace string in database

Tags: mysql, replace, find

I have a very practical question. I have got about 400 articles in my database and in those articles i have links to other articles. During conversion the links were broke. We inserted new menu-link items manually in our CMS. I want to make a script that looks for an (article)id and replace the menu-item id within the internal link for a new menu-item id.

For example:
this is the old internal link in table twsf_content, column introtext:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=140&Itemid=613&ldquo;v.d.Hermels Hoeve&rdquo;</a>
```

this must be the new link in table twsf_content:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=140&Itemid=397&ldquo;v.d.Hermels Hoeve&rdquo;</a>
```

the only thing that changed is the `Itemid` (397 in stead of 613).

We can find article&id (in this case 140) in another table (twsf_menu, column link) and determine what Itemid must be: 397 (column Id) in stead of 613.

There can be more links in one article.

In short: we want to find all links in all articles and replace the Itemid for the new Itemid.

Can somebody give me the code to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: run a loop on each old itemid, find the new id , and update your article's text using something like replace(article_text,'&itemid=<oldid>', '&itemid=<newid>') if your links are formatted in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the stuff to a CSV file, work on that with sed and awk and load it back to the database would be my approach. MySQL isn't good in recursively working with regex and this looks like one-off job.